# Only adding cell-spacing

Tags: html, css

I want to add cell-spacing (only spacing between the tr, and NOT the td) in CSS. I cannot figure this out!!!

I thought I could do this

```
 table
 {
      cell-spacing: 10px;
 }
```

but this adds spacing between the td as well!

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to add spacing between borders of cells, or just spacing between cell contents? If the latter, vertical padding would be a better approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cell-spacing` is incorrect; the property you're looking for is `border-spacing`.

You can specify two values, one for horizontal spacing and one for vertical spacing respectively.

Try this:

```
table
{
    border-spacing: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: @user1083320 If it doesn't work it may be a `CSS Specificity` issue. As he said, more code could reveal the issue...